# Median Function in R: How is it working with the c function

Tags: r

I am so new to R and programming. I started with Python and R.
In my first step of learning, I faced a problem that I believed is so easy, but I don't understand it.
I reviewed the R documentation. I got one example of the result of median, but another one I did not get.

```r
median(1:4)                # = 2.5
```

I got that the result,
but for the other example, I do not know why the result is 3.

```r
median(c(1:3, 100, 1000))  # = 3 [odd, robust] ??
```

What is "robust"?

Comment: The median is the middle value. Of `c(1, 2, 3, 100, 1000)`, 3 is the middle value. When the number of values is even, you usually average the ones on either side:  `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` has no middle value so we take (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5. The median is considered robust because a single, extreme value has less influence on the median than on the mean.

Comment: @dcarlson, post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

The median is the middle value. Of c(1, 2, 3, 100, 1000), 3 is the middle value. When the number of values is even, you usually average the ones on either side: c(1, 2, 3, 4) has no middle value so we take (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5. The median is considered robust because a single, extreme value has less influence on the median than on the mean.